# Batch File to move files with the same string of characters into another folder with that string name

Tags: date, batch-file, directory, filenames

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise and have approximately 20 files per day for the last 365 days that I need to sort.

All of the files are in the same directory. Each file name also contains the date of the file's creation. The date is in the format `MM-DD-YYY` and starts at the 29th character of the file name. The files have the `.csv` extension.

I need to create a batch file to move all of the files with the same date into their own folder and onto another drive on my computer.

Comment: We usually expect people to do their homework before asking the question. This site is to *help* you to do your job, not to do it for you. Next time you ask a question, please specify what you have tried and what you are particularly having trouble with. (You are still welcome to specify that this time too.)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set fileName=%%~a
   set datePart=!fileName:~28,9!
   if not exist "D:\!datePart!" md "D:\!datePart!"
   move "%%a" "D:\!datePart!"
)
```

This script extracts the date part of each file name and uses it as the name of the folder to move the file to. If the folder doesn't exist, it is created, then the file is moved to it.

As written, the script iterates over the `.csv` files in the *current* directory. This is specified by the mask in the `for` loop: `*.csv`. You can change the mask to include a specific path to process, like `C:\path\to\*.csv`.

The target drive is also hard-coded and assumed to be `D:`. Change the corresponding entries of the script if you need to use a different drive.

Detail information on every command used in this script can be obtained by calling the command's built-in help from the command prompt, using either of the below syntaxes:

```
command /?
help command
```